# Reverse Engineering Proguarded-apk

Tags: android, reverse-engineering

I have a task from my lecturer to do some reverse engineering. After doing some tutorials, I can reverse engineer **basic** APK file (with no proguard/dexguard).

My task is finished, but I'm getting curious now. I tried to search this on Google but nothing good/useful was found.

Is it possible to reverse engineering an APK with proguard and how to do it?

**Edit** (dont know why people are voting to close this question, so this is what i've done so far) :

I can reverse engineered a proguarded apk, but the variables are changed (which made my head hurts) :

```
  TextView I;
  EditText J;
  EditText K;
  EditText L;
  CheckBox M;
```

**Can someone help me so i can perfectly reverse engineered it?**

Comment: Is it possible? Sure. It's just more difficult since the code you get is harder for a human to read.

Comment: @Michael do you mean something like my edited question? Can i perfectly reverse engineered it? Thanks

Comment: you can try this link once
but its not with Proguard. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/android-getting-source-code-from-an-apk-file

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "perfectly reverse engineered". If you mean getting the original source code (the way it looked prior to obfuscation), then no, as far as I know you can't. But you can still reverse-engineer the code (i.e. figure out what it does and how it does it), but it will take more effort to do so. It sounds like you're confusing reverse-engineering with decompilation (they're not the same thing).

Comment: You should tell your lecturer to behave himself and stop encouraging his students to infringe someone's copyright

Comment: @NickT from my point of view, its okay because we dont use our skill to do something bad. I think learning is OK

Answer (score 1):

it's possibile and obviously more difficult.

If it's your own .apk, or you have access to the project, then you can use the proguard mapping located here:

```
<project_root>/bin/proguard/mapping.txt
```

otherwise it's just more difficult and you'll need to get used to read and unserstand a lot of guarded bytecode.
Defenetly not easy but possible if you, for instance, have an old version of the apk not guarded.